# Cython : how to pass a list to native

Tags: python, list, cython

I have a cpp library with an API :

```
void sampleClass::newCall(list<string> topic)
```

I am trying to call it from my cython code as:

```
from libcpp.list cimport list as clist
void newCall(clist topic)

cdef class pyClass:
    cdef sampleClass* sc
    def __init__(self):
            self.sc = new sampleClass()

    def newCalling(self):
            abc = ["abc", "xyz"]
            self.sc.newCall(<clist>abc)
```

But i am unable to build cython code.

**error:** 
‘T’ was not declared in this scope
   __pyx_v_self->sc->newCall(((std::list)__pyx_v_abc));

callback.cpp:922:42: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   __pyx_v_self->sc->newCall(((std::list)__pyx_v_abc));

callback.cpp:922:42: error: template argument 2 is invalid
error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

*How can i pass a list as an argument from cython to native library ?*

Comment: This explains what to do: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#standard-library

Comment: Obviously the template parameter is missing, i.e. `clist[string]`.

Comment: Works fine now, thank you so much. Am not very comfortable with cython yet. Appreciate it.